# W3C error doc error? Output tag browser support

Tags: javascript

Was looking at the reference page [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html) : http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html
I copied and pasted the code on my server [here](http://reggi.com/p/html5/clock.html) in separate files. All of the pages are linked correctly but the clock won't show. Just to double check, it wasn't my "server config" I put it on jsfiddle.net [here](http://jsfiddle.net/reggi/Dy8PU/): http://jsfiddle.net/reggi/Dy8PU/.

Fails: **MAC / FIREFOX 3.6.13**
Wins: **MAC / FIREFOX 4.0.b8**

Is this dummy example code?

```
<!-- clock.html -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Clock</title>
  <script src="clock.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>The time is: <output id="clock"></output></p>
 </body>
</html>

/* clock.css */
output { font: 2em sans-serif; }

/* clock.js */
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('clock').value = new Date();
}, 1000);
```

UPDATE:

- The W3C code above works on only the NEWEST Beta releases of certain browsers
- Below are some viable current javascript workarounds

Comment: This is HTML5, which is neither fully standardized nor fully supported in all browsers yet. What OS/browser/version were you trying this on? Also, your JSFiddle should _only_ have the contents of the body tag for the "HTML" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dy8PU/6/

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, the Output tag does not have a .value (in most browser implementations at this time).  If you wish to add some text as a child element, you would want to change it to use .innerHTML.

```
/* clock.js */
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = new Date();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually <output> does have a .value attribute, it's just not implemented yet.

Comment: Interesting definition of the word "have".  "I *have* Jessica Beals's phone number, it's just not implemented yet..."

Comment: "have" as in, it's a new feature we added to the spec (as is <output> in general).

Comment: Usually "have" means, something that is not imaginary.